# jQuery Masonry - I want the div to scroll, not the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

Let me describe what I'm trying to achieve.  On the left side of the browser I have all types of check boxes and radio buttons used to filter data.  On the right side I'm displaying that data using jQuery Masonry.  Now when the data set it large you have to scroll down on the page.  I want to specify a height on the div and scroll down on it so users can see what their filter choices were at all times.  Has anyone done this with Masonry?  I've "googled" on several different occasions and can't seem to find anyone who has done this.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain WHY this worked, only that it worked purely for my own purposes.

```
<style type="text/css">
#results {overflow: auto;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {           
        $("#results").masonry({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            isFitWidth: true,
            isAnimated: true
          }).css("height", "450px");
</script>
```

I haven't looked at this in anything but Chrome yet but I'll be testing it more thoroughly before rolling it out.